# Limits for each part of the improper integral, why?

Tags: improper-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

My handbooks "says" that a limit must be calculated for each part of the improper integral.
When using the same limit for all parts, it is called the Cauchy Principal Value.
My question is, what the difference is whether you use one limit for all parts or a limit for each part of the improper integral?

The improper integral has been defined as follows: 
$$\int _{a}^{c}\!f \left( x \right) {dx}$$
$$\int _{a}^{c}\!f \left( x \right) {dx}=\lim _{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}
 \left( \int _{a}^{b-\epsilon}\!f \left( x \right) {dx} \right) +\lim 
_{\mu\rightarrow 0} \left( \int _{b+\mu}^{c}\!f \left( x \right) {dx}
 \right)
$$
And this is the CPV:
$$
\int _{a}^{c}\!f \left( x \right) {dx}=\lim _{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}
 \left( \int _{a}^{b-\epsilon}\!f \left( x \right) {dx}+\int _{b+
\epsilon}^{c}\!f \left( x \right) {dx} \right) 
$$

Comment: There is no difference if $f(b)$is a finite value. The question arises if $f(b)$ is infinite. Roughly, if you use two different limits close to $b$, i.e. with  $\mu\neq\epsilon$ both integrals tend to infinity and the sum is infinity or undetermined depending of signs. If you use $\mu=\epsilon$, in some cases (not all cases), when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ , there is a finite limit for the sum. Then a Cauchy Principal Value exists.

Comment: @JJacquelin, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cases in which the improper integral does not exist while the CPV still may exist. For example, take a look at the function

$$f(x)=\frac 1x$$

on the interval $[-1, 1]$.